# Compact Sets in Projective Space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Consider the projective space ${\mathbb P}^{n}_{k}$ with field $k$.  We can naturally give this the Zariski topology.

**Question:**  What are the (proper) compact sets in this space?

**Motivation:** I wanted nice examples of spaces and their corresponding compact sets; usually my spaces are Hausdorff and my go-to topology for non-Hausdorff-ness is the Zariski topology.  I wasn't really able to find any proper compact sets which makes me think I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ is a Noetherian topological space, so *every* subset is (quasi)compact. Moreover every closed subset is complete (the analogue of compactness in algebraic geometry).

Comment: Everything Zhen writes in his great comment is absolutely correct and relevant:+1. Readers not used to algebraic geometry (this excludes Zhen and many others!) should beware, however, that  completeness is  not a purely topological notion, but depends on the scheme-theoretic structure. For example $\mathbb A^1_k$ is *not* complete but is homeomorphic to $\mathbb P^1_k$ which *is* complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in for a big surprise, james:  **every subset of $\mathbb P^n_k$ is quasi-compact.**
This is true more generally for any noetherian space, a space in which  every  decreasing  sequence of  closed sets is stationary.
However: **the compact subsets of $\mathbb P^n_k$ are the finite sets of points such that no point is in the closure of another.**

**Reminder**
 A topological space $X$ is quasi-compact if from every open cover of  $X$ a finite cover can be extracted. A compact space is a Hausdorff quasi-compact space.

**Bibliography** Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Chapter II, §4,2.

Comment: Ah, this is nice.  I kept seeing "quasi-compact" but I mistook the definition!  You note then that there are compact subsets though --- what is the difference between the compact subsets and the quasi-compact subsets?